# How to show custom post type in all post section?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I want to show my custom post type `live-blog` in the all post listing page ie. [Here](http://www.wordpress.com:8080/wp-admin/edit.php)

So for that I am using `pre_get_posts` hook in order to show `live-blog` and posts together on that page.

```
    function show_custom_post_type_in_listing($query) {
        if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            if ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_archive() || $query->is_feed() ) {
                $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'live-blog'));
            }
        }
    }
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'show_custom_post_type_in_listing');
```

This works well in listing the `live-blog` in all posts section but it breaks when I filter the posts on the basis of category.

My `URL` becomes

[Here](http://www.wordpress.com:8080/wp-admin/edit.php?s=&post_status=all&post_type=Array&_wpnonce=52e69e14a7&_wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit.php%3Fs%26post_status%3Dall%26post_type%3Dpost%26action%3D-1%26m%3D0%26cat%3D15%26post_format%26seo_filter%26readability_filter%26filter_action%3DFilter%26paged%3D1%26action2%3D-1&action=-1&m=0&cat=15&post_format=&seo_filter=&readability_filter=&filter_action=Filter&paged=1&action2=-1)

Here `post_type` is set to array which gives invalid post type.

Is there any way to fix this

I want to show my custom post type and post in all post section no matter what filter is done